# require is not defined in an electron app

Tags: javascript, electron

I am new to electron. While learning it i came across `require not define` error on browserwindow. So i searched about it and find out we should need to add  `nodeIntegration: true,` so i did it but still it doesnt solve my problem.

here is my app.js (entry file)

```js
function createWindow() {
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });
  win.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, "index.html"),
      protocol: "file",
      slashes: true,
    })
  );

  win.on("close", () => {
    win = null;
  });
}

app.on("ready", createWindow);
```

and my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>main renderer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>main renderer</h1>
    <script>
        require("./index.js")
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: this is the error image]

Comment: `require` does not exist in pure javascript. You need to import *some* script into the page using normal html script tags and their `src` attribute or have a build pipeline that does those kind of things for you. Where did you get the idea that `require("./index.js")` would just work?

Comment: hey we can use node modules using electron. we are not creating web apps instead we are creating desktop apps which has access to them.

Comment: what is your electron version .